# How to register a local directory as a composer package

Tags: wordpress, composer-php

I can't figure out how to register a local directory as a composer package. I found lots of information about registering a local folder that is either a git repository or a composer package or even a zip hosted somewhere.

However I want to register a folder on my local machine, residing in the same repository as my wordpress installation (using wordplate) that is neither a git repository nor a composer package as it doesn't contain any composer.json.

What I try at the moment is to register it like this under `repositories`:

```
{
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "local/contact-form-7-mailchimp-extension",
                "type": "wordpress-plugin",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "type": "path",
                    "url": "resources/plugins/contact-form-7-mailchimp-extension",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
```

Add `"local/contact-form-7-mailchimp-extension": "*"` under `"require"`,
add `"local/contact-form-7-mailchimp-extension"` in `"public/plugins/{$name}"` under `"extras"` > `"installer-paths"`.

Running `composer install` however doesn't install it and gives no information at all. Don't even know if it found the url or not..

Is it even possible to install a local directory like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [path repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) to install packages from a different path into your project.

> However I want to register a folder on my local machine, residing in the same repository as my wordpress installation (using wordplate) that is neither a git repository nor a composer package as it doesn't contain any composer.json.

For this to work, your plugin inside the folder will need a composer.json, though. This is necessary for composer to recognize this folder as a package in the first place. Fortunately, it can be as simple as this:

```
{
    "name": "local/contact-form-7-mailchimp-extension",
    "description": "My Contact Form-extension using mailchimp",
    "type": "wordpress-plugin",
    "version": "dev-master"
}
```

Assuming the plugin is in the directory `resources/plugins/contact-form-7-mailchimp-extension`, you can now register this path as a repository path, meaning composer will look inside this folder for a composer.json and when your wordpress-project requires the provided package it will (by default) be symlinked into vendor.

The wordpress project's composer.json then needs these entries (the options for the repository are the defaults and can be left out, this is just to show how to disable symlinking, should you need that):

```
{
    ...,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url":"resources/plugins/contact-form-7-mailchimp-extension",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "local/contact-form-7-mailchimp-extension": "dev-master",
        ...
    }
}
```

When composer installs the package, it should tell you where it installed it from, i.e. you should find the path from the repository in there.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer! done like you suggested: added composer.json file to those plugins, updated them into the repositories array, added them to `require` with the name I entered in each composer.json... run `composer install` .. nothing. Doesn't even show a folder under `/vendor`, neither any error message

Comment: When I have some time, I will try this myself with a basic wordpress installation. Have you tried adding the verbose-flag `composer install -vvv` and check if it finds the additional repository?

Comment: `composer install -vvv` didn't change anything, I don't know why but when I just tried to use `composer require my/package:dev-master` it installed everything, even the other packages. (my/package is just a placeholder here, as I found out "contact-form-7-mailchimp-extension" is actually listed on wp-packagist, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Glad to hear it's solved. Just create a follow up question, if you encounter any more issues

Comment: Thanks for your help! Still don't understand what happened, my guess is I should have deleted the composer.lock and it would also work with composer install? not sure although

Comment: Could be that it was the composer cache or a quirk with symlinking/copying the path. Instead of deleting the composer.lock maybe deleting the vendor folder will help, so that Composer is forced to "reinstall" the symlink/copy the folder